# Сканирование Wi-Fi из Linux при помощи Python

Tags: python, сеть, wifi, raspberry-pi

При медленном, но верном изучении как работает всё-всё-всё, родилась смешанная идея, а именно, я хочу написать Python скрипт, который постоянно хостится на моём Raspberry Pi 3B, подключенном к домашней сети Wi-Fi и каждый раз, когда видит, что к этой сети подключилось устройство с определенным MAC, а именно MAC моего телефона, то посылает магический пакет (WOL) мне на ПК  и о чудо, придя домой после тяжелого дня я захожу в комнату, а ПК уже готов к работе. Из всего необходимо у меня есть ПК с включенным WOL, домашняя сеть, Raspberry Pi, телефон, немного знаний в Python, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте этот [пример снифа](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f00d6208024d8aa3fe8b315889a69f4403c04c6/scapy__examples/sniff__wifi__arp.py):

```
# https://github.com/secdev/scapy
# pip install scapy
from scapy.all import *


"""
Here is another tool that will constantly monitor all interfaces on a machine and print all ARP request 
it sees, even on 802.11 frames from a Wi-Fi card in monitor mode. Note the store=0 parameter to sniff() 
to avoid storing all packets in memory for nothing. 
"""


def arp_monitor_callback(pkt):
    if ARP in pkt and pkt[ARP].op in (1,2):  # who-has or is-at
        return pkt.sprintf("%ARP.hwsrc% %ARP.psrc%")

sniff(prn=arp_monitor_callback, filter="arp", store=0)
```

Comment: Но ведь сетевая карта RPI не поддерживает режим монитора

Comment: Интересно, а как тогда снифать?